# Why some varaiables need %% and others don't in Windows batch files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

For example, this:

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 30 -c:a aac "%~n1_OUT.mp4"
```

Does not need %%1 and %%~n1 respectively.

But this:

```
FOR /f %%f in ('dir /b .') DO somecommand %%f
```

Needs %%, otherwise it's not working.

Can somebody explain any logical reason for this chaotic design?

Comment: `%1` is an argument reference in a batch file, `%f`/`%%f` is a `for` meta-variable. Refer to this for more information about what exactly happens: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699) For a logical reason: ask Microsoft. My personal opinion: it appears to me like it just happened rather than a well planned development…

Comment: In the command prompt window it is not possible to execute a command line which references __batch file__ arguments as no batch file is processed, just a single command line. In a batch file it is possible to reference arguments passed to the batch file on starting it. Run in a command prompt window `call /?` and read the output help. So there can be used `%0`, `%~1`, `%~dp2`, etc., i.e. batch file __argument__ references) in a batch file and of course __environment variable__ references with immediate expansion like `%SystemRoot%`.

Comment: Next there can be used also __loop variable__ references with `%I` or `%~J` or `%~dpK` in command prompt window. But how to differ a loop variable reference from a batch file argument reference on processing a batch file? The solution defined by the developer of `COMMAND.COM` in MS-DOS was doubling the percent sign of a loop variable reference on being used in a batch file. So there __must__ be used in a batch file `%%I`, `%%~J`, `%%~dpK`, ... because that is the __required__ syntax.as the help output on running `for /F` explains in fourth paragraph on first page.

Comment: A syntax discussion is useless after 40 years of usage of this syntax in batch files processed by `COMMAND.COM` of MS-DOS, Windows 95/98/ME and `cmd.exe` of all Windows NT based Windows versions.

Answer (score 2):

The percent-sign `%` is used by `cmd.exe` and also its predecessor `command.com` to mark expansion<sup>1</sup> of environment variables (like `%VAR%`), `for`-loop meta-variables (like `%I`/`%%I`), and argument references in batch files (like `%1`).

There are two distinct parsing modes, which behave differently when it comes to `%`-expansion:

- Command line mode:

  - There are no command line arguments, hence no argument references are supported.
  - Empty (undefined) variables are not expanded, meaning that `%VAR%` is kept as is when an environment variable `VAR` is not set.
  - There is no escaping of `%`-signs supported, so `%%VAR%%` results in `%` + *value of `VAR`* + `%`.
- Batch file mode:

  - Batch files may have arguments, which are expanded by argument references like `%1`.
  - Empty (undefined) variables are expanded to a blank string.
  - Escaping of the `%`-sign is supported in that `%%` represents a literal `%`.

Of course I cannot tell why the developers decided the parser to behave that way, but I believe there are several factors contributing:

- The command line mode existed before batch file mode, the latter of which required introduction of support for arguments, which in turn led to the demand to let the parser distinguish between variable or argument references.
- When the `for` command was introduced<sup>2</sup>, the developers decided to use the `%`-sign too to mark loop meta-variables, leading to conflicts in command line mode, particularly because empty variables remain: For instance, an expression like `%foo%bar` results in *the value of `foo`* + `bar` when variable `foo` is set, but otherwise to *value of `%f`* + `oo` + *value of `%b`* + `ar` when loop variables `%f` and `%b` exist, and so on. This is particularly because `for` parses the command line a second time after the initial potential expansion of environment variables.
- Introduction of batch file mode and the conflicts coming from the `for` parser probably led to the decision of improved handling of `%`-expansion in that undefined variables are treated differently by expanding such to empty strings. In order to still be able to yield literal `%`-symbols, escaping like `%%` was introduced: For example, a text like `10% plus 20%` could not be returned without escaping since a variable named *<kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `plus 20`* is most likely undefined; however, specifying `10%% plus 20%%` results in the literal string `10% plus 20%`.

Anyway, the `%`-escaping in batch file mode is the intrinsic reason for why `for` meta-variables need to be specified like `%%I` (in contrast to `%I` in command line mode) in order for them to survive the escaping, resulting in `%I`, which is then recognised by the `for` command parser that comes into play after `%`-expansion.

For detailed information about what exactly happens, refer to: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699)

---

<sub>1)  The term expansion means to replace an expression (like `%VAR%`) by the string value it refers to (like the one stored in the respective environment variable named `VAR`) while parsing.</sub>
<sub>2)  Although I do not know whether the `for` command was introduced before or after implementation of the batch file mode.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Command started from console window use single percent sign in for loop varible, but script files uses doubled percent sign. Its by design, well documented. Nothing chaotic..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for